# Why is "trigger warning" said like that

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

I know what is a "trigger warning" I wanted to know what trigger refers to in it

Or if someone knows how the phrase developed to be used with the word trigger

Comment: Have you done any research on this topic? If so, what? Any dictionary should explain the etymology behind a phrase. What specifically are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

A **[trigger warning](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/trigger-warning)** is a message informing an audience that the following image, text, video etc., may contain distressful material.

If you know what [**a trigger's**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigger_(firearms)) function is, it becomes easy to understand how its metaphorical meaning arose.

A trigger by its very nature is a highly sensitive mechanism, very little pressure is required for it to be pressed and potentially cause permanent damage or lethal harm.

When someone says that a particular image, sound, word or phrase might *trigger* a negative response they are describing a person's reaction as being highly sensitive. This type of reaction is often a byproduct of [PSTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-traumatic_stress_disorder)

> PTSD symptoms may result when a traumatic event causes an over-reactive adrenaline response, **which creates deep neurological patterns in the brain. These patterns can persist long after the event that triggered the fear, making an individual hyper-responsive to future fearful situations.** During traumatic experiences, the high levels of stress hormones secreted suppress hypothalamic activity that may be a major factor toward the development of PTSD.
> *Wikipedia*

[image]

Comment: Trigger warnings also feature in discussions about autism. They may be needed to warn people on the spectrum about potentially problematic topics or situations.